# How to fetch event log of security level in windows system using command and without running PowerShell in administration mode

Tags: node.js, powershell

I am building a desktop application using electron where I need to fetch the event logs present in security type event. I tried accessing the data through the command as shown:

```
exec('PowerShell.exe Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Newest 5', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      // console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

But I get error stating "Requested registry access is not allowed". This will not be the issue when I run Powershell in administration mode manually. I am able to access Application and System type event logs using the same command but by replacing Security to Application and System respectively. Is it possible to get the eventlog of security without running in administrator mode. If yes please guide me as this is my first experience of building desktop application in electron.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://techibee.com/sysadmins/how-to-grant-permissions-to-view-security-event-log-in-windows-server-2003-and-2008/2116

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to fetch the detail from the normal windows pc and not the windows server. Is there any way to run the above mentioned script in elevated mode of the powershell.

Comment: Ok I got the solution. Referred the link  https://www.edwardbeazer.com/run-electron-applications-with-admin-privileges-in-windows/